# How to read two lines at a time from a input file and add them to an object?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I am trying to read lines from a text file two lines at a time, and then adding these lines to an object called Record like this: for example it the text file content is like:

```
course
computer Science
plant
flower.gif
waterfall
A lot of water falling.
waterfall
waterfall.jpg
```

then the program should read in the first two lines of the file (lines 1 and 2) and create `Record Id1 = new Record("course", "text", "computer science")` and then read the next two lines (lines 3 and 4) and create `Record Id2 = new Record("plant", "image", "flower.gif")` etc. and so on.

However my code doesn't work the way I want it to, mainly it confuses the Strings `inputLine1` and `inputLine2`. For example: the code should create `Record Id1 = new Record("course", "text", "computer science")`, it doesn't, but instead creates `Record Id1 = new Record("computer science", "text", "")`. so it reads in the first line and then replaces that with the second line. And the same thing with `Record Id2 = new Record("plant", "image", "flower.gif")`, it creates `Record Id2 = new Record("flower.gif", "image", "")`.

Here is my code:

```
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader inputFile = null;
    try {
        inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    String inputLine1, inputLine2;
    OrderedDictionary newTree = new OrderedDictionary();
    try {
        while ((inputLine1 = inputFile.readLine()) != null && (inputLine2 = inputFile.readLine()) != null){
            Record newRecord;
            if(inputLine2.endsWith(".jpg") || inputLine2.endsWith(".gif")){
                newRecord = new Record(new Pair(inputLine1, "image"), inputLine2);
            } else if(inputLine2.endsWith(".wav") || inputLine2.endsWith(".mid")){
                newRecord = new Record(new Pair(inputLine1, "audio"), inputLine2);
            } else {
                newRecord = new Record(new Pair(inputLine1, "text"), inputLine2);
            }

            if(newTree.get(newRecord.getKey()) == null){
                newTree.put(newRecord);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "confuses the Strings inputLine1 and inputLine2" means.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Be precise. Also, what's the point of trying to read lines if a FileNotFoundException is thrown when creating the reader?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So in the example where the code should create `Record Id1 = new Record("course", "text", "computer science")`, it doesn't, but instead creates `Record Id1 = new Record("computer science", "text", "")`. so it reads in the first line and then replaces that with the second line, if that makes sense? And the same thing with `Record Id2 = new Record("plant", "image", "flower.gif")`, it creates `Record Id2 = new Record("flower.gif", "image", "")`

Comment: You are showing us new Record("course", "text", "computer science"), when your code is  new Record(new Pair(inputLine1, "audio"), inputLine2);  Maybe show us your record class.  Since you are getting "image", your inputLine2 must be correct

Comment: Use your debugger, or println() in the code. If the values of inputLine1 and inputLine2 are what you expect them to be, then the problem is in the classes Record/Pair. That you didn't post.

Comment: I just tried printing inputLine1 and inputLine2, and saw that inputLine1 was printing everything in the file and inputLine2 is printing empty lines.

Comment: @JBNizet the Record class creates an object that stores `Pair` object and a String `data`. and the `Pair` class creates an object that stores two Strings `word` and `type`. I can add that to the original post if needed?

Comment: Then that means that the file doesn't contain what you think it contains. It has a blank line after each non-blank line.

Comment: @JBNizet so the code is right then? I'll remake the file and see what happens. thank you all for the help!

Comment: Thank you all for the reply! I realised that some of the words in my file had capital letters which was automatically added, so I add to get a bit of code which converted everything to lower case including user input. And now everything works!  ^^

Answer (score 0):

The validation code you have wrote for jpg and gif etc., look ok but when its about reading two lines and concating them you should use one input read line and read twice in one go. Then concat it. That should work..